# Modify pandas dataframe imported from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i've a big database imported from a csv file (using pd.read_csv), here's how it look in csv file:

```
      0       1       2
0   Milan   Draw    Juventus
1    2.47    3.24    3.03
2    2.45    3.23    3.06
0   Napoli  Draw    Parma
1    1.45    4.41    7.38
2    1.45    4.40    7.36
3    1.46    4.39    7.33
4    1.47    4.33    7.14
5    1.47    4.33    7.13
6    1.47    4.34    7.10
7    1.43    4.54    7.70
0   Fiorentina  Draw    Pisa
1    2.86    3.50    2.45
2    2.92    3.51    2.40
3    3.14    3.55    2.25
4    2.79    3.45    2.61
```

I need the dataframe to look like this:

```
      0         1         2       3       4
0   Milan   Juventus     2.47    3.24    3.03
1   Milan   Juventus     2.45    3.23    3.06
2   Napoli  Parma       1.45     4.41    7.38
3   Napoli  Parma       1.45     4.40    7.36
4   Napoli  Parma       1.46     4.39    7.33
5   Napoli  Parma       1.47     4.33    7.14
6   Napoli  Parma       1.47     4.33    7.13
7   Napoli  Parma       1.47     4.34    7.10
8   Napoli  Parma       1.43     4.54    7.70
9   Fiorentina  Pisa     2.86    3.50    2.45
10  Fiorentina  Pisa     2.92    3.51    2.40
11  Fiorentina  Pisa     3.14    3.55    2.25
12  Fiorentina  Pisa     2.79    3.45    2.61
```

It's very easy to do it in excel with a formula but i would like to be able to do it in python since the csv file is very very big so managing with pandas is way faster but i don't know if it is possible nd how to do it...thanks!

Doing as suggested df=pd.read_csv(r"G:\PLUTO\odds2.csv",sep=",") got me this

```
   Unnamed: 0           0     1         2
0            0       Milan  Draw  Juventus
1            1        2.88  3.58      2.46
2            2        2.84  3.56       2.5
3            0      Napoli  Draw     Parma
4            1        2.44  3.35      3.08
5            2         2.5   3.3      3.03
6            3        2.48  3.31      3.05
7            4        2.49   3.3      3.05
8            5        2.46  3.38      3.02
9            6        2.49  3.37      2.99
10           7        2.48   3.4      2.98
11           0  Fiorentina  Draw      Pisa
12           1        3.05  3.23      2.53
13           2        3.04  3.24      2.53
14           3        3.22  3.25      2.41
15           4        3.23  3.24      2.41
```

Both method worked out adding "index_col=0" in the read-csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"G:\PLUTO\odds.csv", sep=",", index_col=0)
```

Thanks to both guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('eestlane.txt', sep=r"\s+")
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'zero_for_names'})
df[['new1','new2']] = df.loc[df['zero_for_names'] == 0, ['0','1']].reindex(df.index, method='ffill')
df = df[df['zero_for_names'] != 0].drop(columns='zero_for_names').reset_index(drop = True)
df=df[['new1','new2','0','1','2']]
df.columns=[str(i) for i in range(len(df.columns))]
```

Output:

```
             0     1     2     3     4
0        Milan  Draw  2.47  3.24  3.03
1        Milan  Draw  2.45  3.23  3.06
2       Napoli  Draw  1.45  4.41  7.38
3       Napoli  Draw  1.45  4.40  7.36
4       Napoli  Draw  1.46  4.39  7.33
5       Napoli  Draw  1.47  4.33  7.14
6       Napoli  Draw  1.47  4.33  7.13
7       Napoli  Draw  1.47  4.34  7.10
8       Napoli  Draw  1.43  4.54  7.70
9   Fiorentina  Draw  2.86  3.50  2.45
10  Fiorentina  Draw  2.92  3.51  2.40
11  Fiorentina  Draw  3.14  3.55  2.25
12  Fiorentina  Draw  2.79  3.45  2.61
```

Explanation:

- use `read_csv` to get a 3-column dataframe with an index that contains 0 only for rows with names
- use `reset_index` to get an index without duplicates, and `rename` to change the original index to a column named `zero_for_names`
- create two new columns `new1, new2` and use masking on `zero_for_names` together with `reindex` and its `ffill` method arg to prepare these columns to be the first two columns of the target output specified in the question
- use `zero_for_names` to filter out original name rows, then drop this column and use `reset_index` to get a new index without gaps
- rearrange the columns into the desired order
- update `df.columns` to match the desired column names (integers as strings) shown in the question.

Comment: Hi, don't know if i'm doing something wrong but got this error: KeyError: "None of [Index(['0', '1'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]" at the line "df[['new1','new2']] = df.loc[df['ze..."  Also noticed that after reading csv file wit sep=r'\s+' the result is only one column with all values separeted by a comma and a new index

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
def isfloat(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", sep=r"\s+")  # <-- you may to adjust sep= accordingly

# make sure the columns are of type int
df.columns = map(int, df.columns)

mask = df.applymap(isfloat)
x = df[mask].copy()
df[mask] = np.nan
df[[3, 4, 5]] = x

df[[0, 1, 2]] = df[[0, 1, 2]].ffill()
df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns=1)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             0         1     2     3     4
0        Milan  Juventus  2.47  3.24  3.03
1        Milan  Juventus  2.45  3.23  3.06
2       Napoli     Parma  1.45  4.41  7.38
3       Napoli     Parma  1.45  4.40  7.36
4       Napoli     Parma  1.46  4.39  7.33
5       Napoli     Parma  1.47  4.33  7.14
6       Napoli     Parma  1.47  4.33  7.13
7       Napoli     Parma  1.47  4.34  7.10
8       Napoli     Parma  1.43  4.54  7.70
9   Fiorentina      Pisa  2.86  3.50  2.45
10  Fiorentina      Pisa  2.92  3.51  2.40
11  Fiorentina      Pisa  3.14  3.55  2.25
12  Fiorentina      Pisa  2.79  3.45  2.61
```

Comment: Also with your method i'm getting thsi error: " ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ',Home,Draw,Away' " at line df.columns = map(int, df.columns)

Comment: @eestlane You probably want to adjust the parameter to `sep=","`

Comment: Sorry for being dumb, edited the result adjusting as you suggested, but always got same error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Unnamed: 0'"  when executing df.columns = map(int, df.columns)

Comment: @eestlane When loading the dataframe try to select only columns you want: `df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", sep=r",")[['0', '1', '2']]`

Comment: thanks, it worked as i edited my original post by only adding "index_col=0", also for you method, appreciated the help!